# C# F# MVC 3 template deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, f#, asp.net-mvc-templates

I've recently started to explore Daniel Mohl "F# C# ASP.NET MVC3" template.

Can anyone share on how this type of project should be deployed to IIS7??

Thanks.

Comment: If you want help it is best to say what you have tried and what didn't work.  Linking to the template is probably a good idea as well

Answer (score 2):

You deploy it pretty much the same way you'd deploy a "normal" ASP.NET MVC3 website, but there is one extra step: you need to make sure your deployed website will have access to `FSharp.Core.dll`.

If you have admin access to your server, you can simply install the F# redistributable; if not, you'll need to make sure `FSharp.Core.dll` is included when you publish or create a deployment package. The way I handled this in our website (written in MVC3 with C# + F#) was to manually add a reference to `FSharp.Core` to the website project, then right-clicked the reference, clicked properties, then set "Copy Local" to `true`. If you use any assemblies from the F# Powerpack, you'll need to do the same for them.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, the template consists of a C# Web Application that references F# Libraries (DLL) project which contains some of the functionality (namely, controllers and the model).

From the deployment point of view, this is just a normal C# Web Application with some referenced DLLs (created in F#) that will be copied to the `bin` directory, so the standard deployment procedure should for Web Applications should work just fine. I didn't try it myself now, but try:

- Publish application to some folder (right click on C# web project in the solution explorer)
- Copy that directory to your web server
- Follow the usual IIS configuration steps (see [for example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0#DeployonIIS7))